# Adding allow all to 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in AWS Gateway response using CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I am using CDK to create API endpoints. I would like to set 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' to allow all in the header responses. Here is what I have tried

```
api.addGatewayResponse('4xx-error-response', {
        type: ResponseType.DEFAULT_4XX ,
        statusCode: '400',
        responseHeaders: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': `*`
        },
        templates: {
            'application/json': '{ "message": "Access denied", "statusCode": "403", "type": "$context.error.responseType" }'
        }
    });
```

When I try to deploy this, I get the following error

> Resource handler returned message: "Invalid mapping expression specified: Validation Result: warnings : [], errors : [Invalid mapping expression specified: *]

Question: How do I add a gateway response like in the below screenshot using CDK

[image]

Answer (score 1):

in response header instead of * for Access-Control-Allow-Origin you'll have to use '*'.

Like this:

```
 api.addGatewayResponse('invalid-endpoint-error-response', {
      type: ResponseType.MISSING_AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN,
      statusCode: '500',
      responseHeaders: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "'*'",
      },
      templates: {
        'application/json': '{ "message": $context.error.messageString, "statusCode": "488", "type": "$context.error.responseType" }'
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

```js
const resource = api.addGatewayResource('MyResource', {params...});

   
resource.addCorsPreflight({
      allowOrigins: api.Cors.ALL_ORIGINS // eqivalent to ['*']
      allowCredentials: true, // optional for credentials
    });
```

According to the [AWS CORS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html) You need to set more than one header, so I would just use the method that is doing that for me.

The CDK test directories are a good source of information, next to the official docs. You may find there some useful examples. [Here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/tree/main/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-apigateway/test) the ApiGateway insides.